# How to make a Propeller shape Using For-Loops?

Tags: c++, loops

We've been asked to create a program that would generate a propeller shape composed of four right triangles. The size depends on the input.

A sample output would be like this:

```
Enter a number for the size: 5

         *****
    *    ****
    **   ***
    ***  **
    **** *
    ***** *****
         * ****
        **  ***
       ***   **
      ****    *
     *****
```

This is my code so far: but my error is my output is not exactly what it should be .. one triangle is not aligned. What could be the reason?

```
                this is my output :

                   *****
              *    ****
              **   ***
              ***  **
              **** *
              ***** 
                   * *****
                  **  ****
                 ***   ***
                ****    **
               *****     *
```

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main ()
{
    int size;

    cout << "Enter a number for the size : " ;
    cin >> size;

    cout <<endl;

    for (int ctr = 0; ctr <= size; ctr++)
    {
        for(int x = 0; x < ctr; x++)
        {
            cout << "*";
        }
        for (int space=size; space >ctr;space--)
        {
            cout <<" ";
        } 
        for (int x2=size; x2 >ctr; x2--)
        {
            cout<<"*";
        };

        cout<<endl;
    }

    for (int ctr2 = 0; ctr2 <=size; ctr2++)
    {
        for (int space2=size; space2 >ctr2; space2--)
        {
            cout<<" ";
        } 
        for (int x3=0; x3 <=ctr2; x3++)
        {
            cout<<"*";
        };
        for (int space3=0; space3<=ctr2;space3++)
        {
            cout<<" ";
        }
        for (int x4=size; x4>=ctr2;x4--)
        {
            cout<<"*";
        }
        cout <<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for dumping your uncommented code on us and asking us to find your bug.  I hope you will use this same approach going forward in your career as a programmer!

Comment: Is it a compliment? If its not I feel sorry. I'm just new in programming and this is not my career and this is just one of my minor subjects. I find it so hard and confusing to be a programmer. Now I admire you guys. :)

Answer (score 2):

Since it is a homework, I dont want to solve this task completely, but at the end of your first for-loop you create a new line (`cout<<endl`). However, the first line of the triangle in the right corner starts at the last line of your first triangle. The easiest way, would be to handle the middle line in a separate case and adjust your other loops of course.

Comment: +1 for actually helping and not just doing the OP's job.

Comment: I did it!!! Thank you @Marik ! I just separated the middle line :) Youre the BOSS! :D

Answer (score 0):

Try comparing your real and expected output, and look at the first character that is different (I did it for you; marked in bold below):

```
     *****
*    ****
**   ***
***  **
**** *
***** *****
     * ****
    **  ***
   ***   **
  ****    *
 *****
```

Then identify a place in your code where another character is printed (use a debugger for that).

Comment: Thanks everyone! Sorry I'm new in this site and also in programming. I'm confused about both rules that I need help . I'm doing your suggestions :) Thanks again!